# Static variable set to null by @Value

Tags: java, spring

My Constants File:

```
 @Component
    public class Constants {
        public static String ROOT_DOMAIN;
        @Value("${setting.rootDomain}")
        private void setRootDomain(String rootDomain) {
            ROOT_DOMAIN = rootDomain;
        }
    ...
    }
```

My settings.properties:

```
setting.rootDomain=example.com
```

My Referring Class and Method:

```
@Component
public class MyServiceClass
{
        public void doSomething()
        {
           System.out.println("Root is:" + Constants.ROOT_DOMAIN);
        }
}
```

But Root Domain is coming as null

[update] 
My spring-master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:/META-INF/spring/local/settings.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:/META-INF/spring/${DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT}/settings.properties</value>                        
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.app">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>  
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.app.dao.api" />

    <!-- Application Context Provider -->
    <bean id="appContextProvider" class="com.myapp.app.ApplicationContextProvider"/>

</beans>
```

And the ApplicationContextProvider class is as follows:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

     private static ApplicationContext context;

     public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
         return context;
     }

     @Override
     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
         context = ctx;
     }
}
```

So yes the files are in classpath

Comment: This looks like a spring context misconfiguration. How does it look like and what is your project structure ?

Comment: Have you tried to change setRootDomain visibility to public? Are you sure that the properties file is in classpath?

Comment: You access the variable directly without autowiring the `Constants` bean, when do you expect Spring to initialize that bean?

Comment: @Catalin added configs

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak the static variable is already set to public

Comment: @Tom unfortunately can't take that approach as this Constant is referred to in too many files for me to change in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Value() gets called on the initialization of the bean , the bean gets initialized on need not on the startup so you will not have the value unless the bean is initialized

Comment: Any way I can get it on startup? Because later on it seems like I am able to get the Constant to its correct value in some other classes and even in the same method.

Comment: yeah when the bean is initialized you will be able to get the value, until then it will be null

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding `@DependsOn` annotation to my annatated `@Bean` as described here [Order of Configuration in SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314418/order-of-configuration-in-springboot)