# Order of Configuration in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to understand how beans that we make using `@Configuration` tends to override the beans that are generated by SpringBoot by default. I have been working on a project where in many cases we create beans for things like ZuulConfigs and the assumption is, whatever we are making shall take precedence over the default generated bean. I have been trying to figure this out but can't. Basically,

1. Is Spring achieving this via some custom class loader
2. If not how is this precedence working. Can I give some precedence in similar manner to my beans
3. Can I generate similar hierarchy in my project,if so how

The help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 24):

Spring AutoConfiguration is used to provide a basic configuration if certain classes are in the classpath or not.

If you want to configure the order in which beans are instantiated by spring you can use

```
@DependsOn("A") 
 public class B {
 ...    
}
```

This would create bean "A", then "B". Hence you can order the configuration depending upon the beans need first to be done. Anyways Spring automatically detects the dependencies by analyzing the bean classes.
for more help check this question 
[Spring Boot AutoConfiguration Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667516/spring-boot-autoconfiguration-order)

Alternative : 
There is also "@AutoConfigureOrder" annotation(where you can prioritise the configuration), you can have a look in the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfigurationSorter.java) for deeper understanding.

Documentation of AutoConfiguration is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)

Answer (score 8):

First of all, class loading and bean creation are two different things. We don't need to create a bean to load a class, however, a class has to be loaded in order to create a bean.

Now, coming back to Spring's example, Spring looks into all the packages configured by `@componentScan` and creates beans of all the classes annotated with `@Bean`, `@Configuration` and/or `@Component`. Spring's container keeps track of all the beans created and hence, when it encounters user defined bean with same name and class type as default bean, it replaces the original definition with user defined one (e.g. we can create our custom `@ObjectMapper` to override Spring boot's own instance). You can also use `@Primary` annotation to make you bean take precedence if another definition with same class exists (documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html)).

Below are the answers for your questions:

1. Spring uses reflection to load the classes and create instances. Although you can load the classes with your custom class loader (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660115/loading-spring-context-with-specific-classloader)), you don't need to worry about it for `@Configuration`.
2. Yes, you can use `@Primary` annotation to give your bean a precedence. You can also use `@Order`([here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)) to define the creation order for your beans.
3. With `@Primary`, `@Order` and `@Qualifier` [annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) you can define your own hierarchy for bean creation.

Comment: I suspected that Spring uses Java reflection to load, but could not find the code that does this - would you point to the file or documentation that shows Spring uses reflection? Thanks.

Comment: @flow2k have a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies) documentation.

Comment: TBH, @Order doesn't help too much with bean autowiring priority - `determineAutowireCandidate` says: `Looks for @Primary and @Priority` - `@Order` is not used there

Answer (score 7):

Just know this: Spring Boot (specifically) auto configuration classes are always *configured* last. After all user beans have been created. Spring Boot auto configuration classes almost always use the `@ConditionalXXXX` annotations to make sure that any beans of the same type/name and other conditions that are configured in your application will take precedence over the Spring Boot *auto-configured* beans.

Comment: Do you have any source ?

Answer (score 7):

> Can I give some precedence in similar manner to my beans

Yes.

A) To define a specific order your Configuration classes will be handled (by the way, a Configuration class does not have to be annotated with `@Configuration` (so-called full definition), but it's enough to be annotated with `@Component`, `@ComponentScan`, `@Import`, `@ImportResource` or just have a method annotated with `@Bean` - so-called lite definition), you should

1) add your Configuration Candidates to your `SpringApplication`'s `primarySource`, for example, in your main method like that

```
SpringApplication.run(
   new Class[]{YourSpringBootApplication.class, Config1.class, Config2.class, ...},
   args);
```

2) and annotate each of your Configuration Candidates with `@Order` annotation, any other ordering means like `Ordered` interface, `@DependsOn` etc will be ignored by `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`, the order in the `primarySource` array will also be ignored.

Then `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` will sort your Configuration Candidates and handle them according the `@Order` annotation value you specified.

B) The precedence can also be achieved by defining your own AutoConfiguration classes. Although both **Configuration and AutoConfiguration** are handled by the same `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`, they **are essentially distinctive machineries**. To do so

1) define in your classpath `/META-INF/spring.factories` file and put in the EnableAutoConfiguration section of it your AutoConfiguration classes like that

```
   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
   your.package.AutoConfig1,your.package.AutoConfig2
```

2) and annotate your AutoConfiguration classes with `@AutoConfigureOrder`, `@AutoConfigureAfter`, or `@AutoConfigureAfter` annotations, any other ordering means again will be ignored.

Like @Strelok pointed out, AutoConfiguration classes, your own and provided e.g. by `spring-boot-autoconfigure` library alike, will be added to the end of the list of Configuration Candidates.

Remember, however, that the **order the Configuration Candidates** will be handled by `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` **does not necessarily coincide with the order the beans** defined by the Configuration classes will be created. For example, you might define your Configuration class that overrides `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` to make your own customization of Tomcat web server like

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedTomcatConfig {

@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
    ...
    return customizedTomcatWebServerFactory;
}
```

but this method will be called right at the moment when your Spring Boot application  decides to create a Web server, regardless of how you defined the precedence for your `EmbeddedTomcatConfig` Configuration class.

> Is Spring achieving this via some custom class loader

There is no need to. Although you could, as always with Spring, define your own `ClassLoader` for `BeanFactory`, standard `ClassLoader` is good enough if everything you need for Configuration in your application is available in the classpath. Please notice, that at first phase `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` does not *load* (i.e. does not *resolve*) the Configuration candidates classes (otherwise, most of the classes in `spring-boot-autoconfigure` library will fail to load). Instead it analyzes their annotations with bytecode analyzer, `ASM` by default. For that purpose, it is just enough to get a binary form, a byte array, of a class to feed it to bytecode analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your @Component to take precedence over other @Component while scanning all the components by spring, use @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE) i.e. the max value to load your component over other.

@Primary is used to give your bean a default preference, we can override the default preference using @Qualifier

Comment: TBH, @Order doesn't help too much with bean autowiring priority - `determineAutowireCandidate` says: `Looks for @Primary and @Priority` - `@Order` is not used there