# how to load @Configuration classes in an order in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

i would like to load @Configuration classes in an order. i have  two configuration classes. i am having a requirement of loading my SampleProperties  class before sampleconfiguration class.

I have tried the following annotations but it is not working as expected.

```
@AutoConfigureAfter(SampleProperties.class )
@AutoConfigureBefore(SampleConfiguration.class)
```

I have put my congiurations class in diff package in order to read configurations classes in an order.using **@Import** function, i am including my configuration classes into my application

**My Main Class:**

```
@Import({SampleProperties.class,SampleConfiguration.class,}) 
public class SampleApplication{  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**My SampleProperties Class**

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(SampleConfiguration.class) 
@ConfigurationProperties("demo")
@Data
public class SampleProperties  {

    private String team;
    private int teamSize;
    private String teamLeader;

}
```

**My sampleconfiguration  Class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef="sampleEntityManager", 
                       transactionManagerRef="sampleTransactionManager",
                       basePackages= {"com.example.demo.repo"})
@AutoConfigureAfter(SampleProperties.class)                    
public class SampleConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    Environment env;



    @Bean(name="sampleDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dmsDataSource() { 

         // functions
        return null;
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sampleEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dmsEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
      // functions
        return null;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sampleTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dmsTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sampleEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
      // functions
        return null;
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me what missing and where am making mistakes?

Comment: i think there is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314418/order-of-configuration-in-springboot

Comment: i tried that too. but not working

Comment: Your `SampleProperties` isn't (or should) be an `@Configuration` object. It should be an `@Component`. Also the `@AutoConfigure` won't help as it isn't an auto configuration. Why is the ordering so important?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `@Order`. I think it can also apply to `@Configuration`, not just `@Component`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use `@Order` annotation.

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class SampleProperties {
   // code
}

@Component
@Order(2)
public class SampleConfiguration {
    // code
}
```